# JPA, flush and Entity Manager sync

Tags: database, jpa, relationship, entitymanager

I'm using Java EE, Netbeans and a facade session bean to implement the JPA layer (eclipselink).

I've a two table for example: Garden (1) ---> Tree (n).

(Script A) Now, I execute this snippet:

```
Garden mGarden = new Garden();
.....
gardenFacade.create(garden)
```

(Script B) Then:

```
Tree oneTree = new Tree();
oneTree.setGarden(mGarden);
treeFacade.create(oneTree);
```

In this way, the entity Tree is correctly added into my database and the foreign key is right.

(Script C) When I invoke:

```
Garden findGarden = gardenFacade.find(gardenId);
int count = findGarden.getTreeCollection().size();
```

I've count = 0 !!!
If I restart glassfish or reload my app and I execute these snippets I've count = 1.

So, I think that this is a problem of Persistence Context Synchronization because if I change my script B with:

```
Tree oneTree = new Tree();
oneTree.setGarden(mGarden);
treeFacade.create(oneTree);

mGarden.getTreeCollection().add(oneTree);
gardenFacade.edit(mGarden);
```

all works correctly!
How can I solve this issue?

EDIT:

```
create --> getEntityManager().persist(entity);
edit ----> getEntityManager().merge(entity);
find ----> getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
```

Comment: Perhaps it's worth inserting the code behind gardenFacade.create()

Comment: Ok, but is a simple persist() call:  getEntityManager().persist(entity);

Comment: Have a look at this [great article](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/03/16/jpa-implementation-patterns-bidirectional-assocations/) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all those calls are using the same hibernate session, and sinc you failed to properly initialize both sides of the collection, of course you don't get anything in the collection:

```
Garden mGarden = new Garden(); // create a new Garden instance
session.persist(mGarden); // now this Garden instance is persistent. 
                          // Its state will be written to the database at the 
                          // next flush
Tree oneTree = new Tree(); // create a new Tree instance
oneTree.setGarden(mGarden); // set the garden of the tree. This is a basic, simple 
                            // Java method call. Nothing will magically add the tree
                            // to the garden collection of trees if you don't do 
                            // it explicitely
session.persist(oneTree); // now this Tree instance is persistent. 
                          // Its state will be written to the database at the 
                          // next flush. 
Garden findGarden = session.get(Garden.class, gardenId); 
    // returns the garden that has the specific ID. It's already in the session: 
    // you created and attached it to the session at the beginning. And you 
    // never added anything to its collection of trees
```

Comment: as this refers to, you need to have your object model correct _and_ your database correct. As it is you don't set the one to many (collection). You need to add the object to the collection as you have done in the change to script B